# C# Word Add-In Trusted Certificate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-office, vsto

[image: Word Trusted Publisher certificate problem]

I made Word Add In using C# whenever I run addin, it shows following error, I enabled all macros in Trust center but it doesn' work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx#Trust) article in MSDN states the following:

> Before a solution can run on user computers, either you must grant trust or users must respond to a trust prompt when they install the solution. To grant trust to the solution, sign the manifests by using a certificate that identifies a known and trusted publisher. See Trusting the Solution by Signing the Application and Deployment Manifests.

As you may see the macro security settings of the host application does't play any role there. You need to sign the manifests by using a certificate. You can read more about that in the [Configuring ClickOnce Trusted Publishers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx) article. Also see the [ClickOnce Security and Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) section in MSDN for more information about ClickOnce installers.